# Algorithm analysis, what counts as key comparisons?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, analysis

I am trying to do analysis on different kind of algorithms, including hybrid algorithm, e.g quick sort + insertion sort, or merge sort + insertion sort

I want to know what actually count as key comparisons when measuring sorting algorithms

insertionsort:

```
def insertionSort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):

        key = arr[i]

        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and key < arr[j]:
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
            j -= 1
            comparisons += 1 # this counts as key comparisons?
        arr[j + 1] = key
```

mergesort

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    global comparisons
    if len(arr) > 1:

        # Finding the mid of the array
        mid = len(arr) // 2

        # Dividing the array elements
        L = arr[:mid]

        # into 2 halves
        R = arr[mid:]

        # Sorting the first half
        mergeSort(L)

        # Sorting the second half
        mergeSort(R)

        i = j = k = 0

        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R): #this is considered comparison>
            comparisons+=1
            if L[i] < R[j]:
                arr[k] = L[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = R[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1

        # Checking if any element was left
        while i < len(L): #no need to include this as comparison?
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(R):
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
```

Comment: what do you mean with key comparison ? **indexes** or **item itself** ?

Comment: What if your array has even number of items ?

Comment: in sorting algorithm you have to do comparisons @ManifestMan

Comment: that is what I'm asking in this question, what should I keep track of when I'm checking for key comparison e.g is this element lesser than others etc

Comment: Generally we compare items based on their current values. But for some case it can be necessary to compare indexes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this based on value, for merge sort.  For a data array randomly generated of size 10 000, I am getting 120 399 key comparisons. Does this look abnormal?

Comment: No it,s not abnormal, it,s looking good!